# My dryer on my laundry center stopped working

Tags: electrical, heating, dryer, washer, 120-240v

Can i run my laundry center on 120v for the washer portion only and disconnect the dryer completely? I only have 1 240v outlet and a 120v outlet with a 20 amp breaker.  I called a repair shop and they said i had to unhook the dryer power portion and I can't figure out how

Comment: What make and model is your laundry center? Do you know what's actually wrong with it?

Comment: In the US dryers are normally plug in devices but with your wording I would guess you are not here I would pull the dryer out a few inches and see if there is a plug in. Thermal safety fuses are a common fault in dryers that keep them from drying.

Comment: Fex831cso is the model# I'm in WI.  The heating element is out in this model.  So I wanted to run just the washer portion on 120v and use my new dryer on 240v

Comment: Is it as simple as disconnecting the dryer motor and hooking up a 120v power cord? I'm very capable of doing this myself but I can't find any info on un hooking the dryer.